# Testing if a shuffled sequence is truly random

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random

I have multiple sequential values between 1-n (n being 10 for this example but can vary) that are shuffled, e.g.:

```
list1 = [1 6 5 3 2 4 7 9 10 8]
list2 = [7 4 8 1 5 9 2 3 10 6]
list3 = [9 2 7 10 4 3 5 1 6 8]
list4 = [8 10 3 2 1 6 7 4 5 9]
list5 = ....
```

How can I test that this shuffling is truly random, and someone didn't apply a method to shuffle it? For example, someone could have divided the data into two chunks 1-5, and 6-10 and shuffled within those chunks. E.g:

```
list9 = [3 1 4 5 2 9 6 8 10 7]
```

or they could have divided the data into two chunks 1-5, and 6-10, flipped (or shuffled) the chunks and then shuffled within those chunks. E.g:

```
list9 = [7 6 10 8 9 2 1 3 5 4]
```

Thanks!

Comment: this is not a well-defined question. for any shuffling you can define a "function".

Comment: when you say that "the shuffling is truly random", do you mean that the shuffling is done in such a way that every possible sequence is equally likely (i.e. a uniform distribution)? certainly the lists had to be generated by some method, which will then place a probability distribution on what a given list would be.

Comment: Yes, every possible sequence is equally likely is one way of looking at it.

Comment: You cannot prove that those constellations were created with a generator producing true random numbers. You can however apply tests for randomness and look whether they are passed.

Comment: @peter what are these tests for randomness? Can you point me to one? that's what I am trying to find out is to test this. Thanks in advance!